# Can the Functional Renormalization Group not generate a flow that is generated perturbatively?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, non-perturbative, 1pi-effective-action

I think I might have stumbled on a calculation that appears to undergo renormalization when you compute it perturbatively, but not when you compute it using the FRG. Consider, for the sake of argument, the effective average action given in Euclidean signature by
$$\Gamma_k[\phi_1, \phi_2] = \int \frac{1}{2}\phi_1 \Delta \phi_1 + \frac{1}{2}\phi_2 \Delta \phi_2 + m_k^2 \phi_1 \phi_2 + \frac{\lambda_k}{4!} \phi_2^4 \ \mathrm{d}^4{x}.$$

I am aware that this theory contains a term with negative mass once you diagonalize the mass matrix. I'm considering it just for the sake of argument.

Now, perturbatively, it seems one gets a renormalization flow for the "mass term". Namely, by means of the diagram

[image: One-loop diagram contributing to the two-point function from a 1 mode to a 2 mode. The diagram has a straight line that starts from 1, has a cross in the middle, has a bubble right after (represented by a circle tangent to the line), and then reaches 2.]

where the cross denotes an insertion of the $\phi_1\phi_2$ vertex. This diagram should be a one-loop contribution to the propagator that starts with a $1$ mode and ends with a $2$ mode, made possible by the $m_k^2 \phi_1 \phi_2$ term in the Lagrangian.

However, let us now consider what happens with the FRG. Computing the second derivative of the EAA, we get
$$\Gamma_k^{(2)} = \begin{pmatrix} \Delta & m_k^2 \\ m_k^2 & \Delta + \frac{\lambda_k}{2} \phi_2^2 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Since this matrix has no instances of the $\phi_1$ field, using it on Wetterich's equation won't lead to any contribution to the running of $m_k^2$, since the term $m_k^2 \phi_1 \phi_2$ can't be generated. Yet, it seems to be renormalized perturbatively.

What is going on here? Is it possible for the non-perturbative calculation not to generate a correction that happens already at the perturbative level?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with FRG, but it looks to me like the difference is that you're not performing the "rescaling" step in the second approach. To all orders in perturbation theory, your quartic interaction will never generate additional quadratic $\phi_1 \phi_2$ terms (although it will generate $\phi_2^2$ terms). The renormalization of $m_k^2$ comes from rescaling the fields to restore the original cutoff, which requires rescaling $m_k^2$ as well.

Comment: In addition to Zack's comment, which sounds like a very likely resolution for this example, another thing to consider in more general examples is that features of the non-perturbative flow can be affected by the choice of ansatz, which here assumes that only the parameters that appear in the bare theory flow. If your ansatz included higher order powers of $\phi_1 \phi_2$, then those could potentially contribute to the flow of $m_k^2$ (beyond the flow due to rescaling).

Comment: @Zack that makes sense. The way I wrote indeed doesn't take rescaling into account. I'll try to do the calculation keeping it in mind and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: @bbrink That makes a lot of sense, thank you for you comment! This time I'm a bit more interested in whether this ansatz would get a flow for $m_k^2$, but I'll keep it in mind =)

Comment: The action describes a $\phi^4$-theory for $\phi_2$ coupled to a free theory for $\phi_1$ by means of a (in terms of $\phi_2$) linear term $\phi_1\phi_2$ which breaks the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-symmetry in the $\phi_2$ sector linearly and explicitly. Such linear terms do not contribute to the RG flow and remain unchanged under it. This is a general statement (see e.g. Sec. 13.3 of . Zinn-Justin, “Quantum field theory and critical phenomena,” Int.Ser.Monogr.Phys. 113 (2002)) not exclusive to FRG about renormalization and explicit linear symmetry breaking.